# angular-ui-router: Load template from external resource ( express app )

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to load a template from a other application (like a express app) via $http?
Or from an other external source?

Answer (score 0):

Not with ui-router alone, though the following lazy loading module for ui-router exists which may help you achieve your goal: ocLazyLoad - https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

An example of how it works (taken from http://plnkr.co/edit/6CLDsz)

```
define([
  'angular', 
  'uiRouter',
  'ocLazyLoad',
  'ocLazyLoad-uiRouterDecorator'
], function (angular) {

  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'oc.lazyLoad.uiRouterDecorator']);

  app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
      loadedModules: ['app'],
      asyncLoader: require
    });

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        template: "<p>Hello {{name}}. Would you like to... <a href='#lazy'>load lazy</a>?</p>",
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      })
      .state('lazy', {
        url: "/lazy",
        lazyModule: 'app.lazy',
        lazyFiles: 'lazy',
        lazyTemplateUrl: 'lazy.html',
        controller: 'lazyCtrl'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

  app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you'll have to use a templateProvider. More clear explanation using an example:

```
      $stateProvider.state('state', {
            url: '/state',
            //templateUrl: 'templates/stateTemplate.html',
            templateProvider: function ($http, $templateCache) {
                var tplUrl = 'http://another.accesible.domain/stateTemplate.html',
                    tpl = $templateCache.get(tplUrl);
                return (!!tpl) ? tpl :
                    $http
                        .get(tplUrl)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            tpl = response.data
                            $templateCache.put(tplUrl, tpl);
                            return tpl;
                        });
            },
            controller: 'stateController as sCtrl',
            params: {
                target: null
            },
            resolve: {
                loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load(['stateController', 'appDataProvider', 'appDataService', 'stateFactory', 'stateService']);
                }],
                resolveObject: function ($window) {
                    var result = $window.localStorage.getItem('resolveObj');                        

                    return result;
                }
            }
        })
```

Hope it helps (late answer I know, but just found this question looking for something else). ocLazyLoad is needed if you don't want to load everything at once when your app starts, but load what is required when it's required. Quite useful if your app's memory footprint is an issue.

Best regards.

Comment: How can I use a temporary template until the $http request finishes?